# Reactive Cocoa Splitting a signal without code duplication?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I am trying to change the label on a button up on the selector being called.

It appears that the code is duplicated. Is there a way perhaps it's not obvious to me right now to have the signal switch after the map ? or no ?

```
[[[pressedStart map:^id(id value) {
    UIButton* button = value;
    BOOL transform = [button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Start"];
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:transform];

}] filter:^BOOL(id value) {
    return [value boolValue];
}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    self.start.titleLabel.text = @"Stop";
}];

[[[pressedStart map:^id(id value) {
    UIButton* button = value;
    BOOL transform = [button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Stop"];
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:transform];
}] filter:^BOOL(id value) {
    return [value boolValue];
}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
   self.start.titleLabel.text = @"Start";
}];
```

Comment: is `self.start` the same as the `button`? Do you subscribe for `pressedStart`signal (or any signals derived from it) anywhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in order to change the button's title, you have to call its `setTitle:forState:` method.

Also please note that using `self` inside the `subscribeNext` block is likely to create a retain cycle (and therefore a memory leak). You can read more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14101656/2128900). You can use `@weakify` / `@strongify` macros or, as mentioned in that answer, use `rac_liftSelectors:withSignals:` method (which IMHO seems to be cleaner).

Your code can be simplified as you actually don't need to split the signal at all. You can use a simple condition inside the `map` block and return the value which should be the button's title after it was pressed. This value will be sent as a `next` value of the resulting signal. You can also use `startWith:` operator to set the initial value (I guess it should be "Start").

```
RACSignal *buttonTextSignal = [[pressedStart map:^id(UIButton *buttonPressed) {
    return [buttonPressed.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Start"] ? @"Stop" : @"Start";
}]
startWith:@"Start"];
[self.start rac_liftSelector:@selector(setTitle:forState:) withSignals:buttonTextSignal, [RACSignal return:@(UIControlStateNormal)], nil];
```

---

What does `rac_liftSelector:withSignals:` do? Each time one of the `signals` sends its `next` value, it invokes the method identified by the `selector` (in this case `setTitle:forState:`). The method is invoked with `next` values of the `signals` as its parameters. So in our case it will initially call:

```
[self.startButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If you wanted to set a single property (let's say `titleLabel.text`), you could bind it with `RAC` macro:

`RAC(self.startButton, titleLabel.text) = buttonTextSignal;`

Unfortunately, it only works for setting properties, and in your case you have to call a method with two arguments, that's why you have to use `rac_liftSelector:withSignals`.

---

As I said, you could achieve the desired result using `subscribeNext`:

```
@weakify(self);
RACSignal *buttonTextSignal = [[[pressedStart map:^id(UIButton *buttonPressed) {
    return [buttonPressed.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Start"] ? @"Stop" : @"Start";
}]
startWith:@"Start"]
subscribeNext:^(NSString *title) {
    @strongify(self);
    [self.startButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}];
```

But as you can see, you should take extra care to avoid a retain cycle, using `@weakify` and `@strongify` macros.

Comment: I am not sure what the last line does can you explain what rac_liftSElector with signals does? I understand what the lifting of te selector does I am not sure what  with signals does.

Comment: I've added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: I also have another question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092146/reactivecocoa-takeuntil-2-possible-signals

Sorry I am really new to reactive cocoa I am still trying to digest the concepts